# capital gains and electric vehicle tax credit with form 1040 NR EZ

Tags: united-states, income-tax, form-1040

This question is regarding income tax in USA for non-resident aliens. In order to show my capital gains and electric vehicle tax credit,

do I need to mention/add/substract anything in the form 1040 NR-EZ

or

do I just fill out the forms f1040s1 and f8936 and let IRS figure out the rest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the instructions](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i1040nre.pdf) (third and sixth boxes in the checklist on the left), capital gains income excludes you from using the EZ version, and you can't claim the EV tax credit on it either. You'll need to use the full 1040NR.